# How to use SnapHelper with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, layout-manager, vertical-scroll

I m stuck with SnapHelper for RecyclerView. I m confused to use it with LayoutManager in Vertical

I already used in Horizontal like

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution maybe help. https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/recyclerviewsnap

As you can see, he said to make sure you set the orientation of layout manager.